# R -openxlsx - delete multiple worksheets

Tags: r, openxlsx

Is there a way to remove multiple worksheets from a workbook in openxlsx?
Or to keep only selected worksheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `removeWorksheet` from `openxlsx` package.

This example is taken out from page 69 of the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf).

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet 1")
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet 2")
writeDataTable(wb, sheet = "Sheet 1", x = iris, tableName = "iris")
writeDataTable(wb, sheet = 1, x = mtcars, tableName = "mtcars", startCol = 10)
removeWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1) ## delete worksheet removes table objects
```

edit:

```r
library(openxlsx)
library(purrr)

nms <- c("Sheet 1","Sheet 2","Sheet 3")

wb <- createWorkbook()

nms %>% 
 walk(~ addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = .))

addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = 'sheet 4')

wb
#> A Workbook object.
#>  
#> Worksheets:
#>  Sheet 1: "Sheet 1"
#>  
#> 
#>  Sheet 2: "Sheet 2"
#>  
#> 
#>  Sheet 3: "Sheet 3"
#>  
#> 
#>  Sheet 4: "sheet 4"
#>  
#> 
#>  
#>  Worksheet write order: 1, 2, 3, 4
#>  Active Sheet 1: "Sheet 1" 
#>  Position: 1

nms %>% 
  walk(~ removeWorksheet(wb, .))

wb
#> A Workbook object.
#>  
#> Worksheets:
#>  Sheet 1: "sheet 4"
#>  
#> 
#>  
#>  Worksheet write order: 1
#>  Active Sheet 1: "sheet 4" 
#>  Position: 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: To my understanding, this only removes 1 sheet at the time, right? So, I should apply it sequentially with a for loop..

Comment: @tzema Yes, you can use a for loop or map/apply functions. I edited the answer using `walk` from `purrr` library.